# The mongo-express/mongodb YAML files works on minikube but not work on my 3 nodes kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I have couple of YAML files for mongo-express/mongodb as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
    name: mongodb-secret
type: Opaque
data:
    mongo-root-username: dXNlcm5hbWU=
    mongo-root-password: cGFzc3dvcmQ=
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongodb-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongodb
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongodb
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongodb
          image: mongo
          ports:
            - containerPort: 27017
          env:
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
              valueFrom: 
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-password

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  labels:
    app: mongodb
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: mongodb
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo-express
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo-express
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo-express
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: mongo-express
          image: mongo-express
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8081
          env:
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-username
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD
              valueFrom: 
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: mongodb-secret
                  key: mongo-root-password
            - name: ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER
              value: mongodb-service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo-express-service
  labels:
    app: mongo-express
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
      nodePort: 30000
      protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mongo-express
```

I can apply above YAML file on local **minikube** cluster when I execute minikube service mongo-express-service.
I can also apply it to my 3 nodes **kubernetes** cluster, but the mongo-express **Pod** seems not available to connect to mongodb-service.

This is my initial troubleshoot.

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME        STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION   INTERNAL-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE             KERNEL-VERSION      CONTAINER-RUNTIME
master-20   Ready    master   35d   v1.19.2   192.168.0.20   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS   4.4.0-186-generic   docker://19.3.13
node1       Ready    <none>   35d   v1.19.2   192.168.0.21   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS   4.4.0-186-generic   docker://19.3.13
node2       Ready    <none>   35d   v1.19.2   192.168.0.22   <none>        Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS   4.4.0-186-generic   docker://19.3.13

$ kubectl get all -o wide
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
pod/mongo-express-749445c6c9-wlnx8       1/1     Running   0          18s   10.244.2.23   node2   <none>           <none>
pod/mongodb-deployment-8f6675bc5-w9wks   1/1     Running   0          22s   10.244.1.20   node1   <none>           <none>

NAME                            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE   SELECTOR
service/kubernetes              ClusterIP      10.96.0.1      <none>        443/TCP          35d   <none>
service/mongo-express-service   LoadBalancer   10.108.20.77   <pending>     8081:30000/TCP   18s   app=mongo-express
service/mongodb-service         ClusterIP      10.98.48.206   <none>        27017/TCP        22s   app=mongodb

NAME                                 READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS      IMAGES          SELECTOR
deployment.apps/mongo-express        1/1     1            1           18s   mongo-express   mongo-express   app=mongo-express
deployment.apps/mongodb-deployment   1/1     1            1           22s   mongodb         mongo           app=mongodb

NAME                                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS      IMAGES          SELECTOR
replicaset.apps/mongo-express-749445c6c9       1         1         1       18s   mongo-express   mongo-express   app=mongo-express,pod-template-hash=749445c6c9
replicaset.apps/mongodb-deployment-8f6675bc5   1         1         1       22s   mongodb         mongo           app=mongodb,pod-template-hash=8f6675bc5


$ kubectl logs mongo-express-749445c6c9-wlnx8
Waiting for mongodb-service:27017...
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 14: mongodb-service: Try again
/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 14: /dev/tcp/mongodb-service/27017: Invalid argument
Sun Nov  8 05:29:40 UTC 2020 retrying to connect to mongodb-service:27017 (2/5)


$ kubectl logs mongodb-deployment-8f6675bc5-w9wks
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 28

...

MongoDB init process complete; ready for start up.

{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:54.631+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"main","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:54.634+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:54.634+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:54.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":1,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"mongodb-deployment-8f6675bc5-w9wks"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:54.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"4.4.1","gitVersion":"ad91a93a5a31e175f5cbf8c69561e788bbc55ce1","openSSLVersion":"OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018","modules":[],"allocator":"tcmalloc","environment":{"distmod":"ubuntu1804","distarch":"x86_64","target_arch":"x86_64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:54.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Ubuntu","version":"18.04"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:54.636+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"net":{"bindIp":"*"},"security":{"authorization":"enabled"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:54.638+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22270,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Storage engine to use detected by data files","attr":{"dbpath":"/data/db","storageEngine":"wiredTiger"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:54.639+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22297,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine. See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem","tags":["startupWarnings"]}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:54.639+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22315,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Opening WiredTiger","attr":{"config":"create,cache_size=479M,session_max=33000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000,close_scan_interval=10,close_handle_minimum=250),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=[recovery_progress,checkpoint_progress,compact_progress],"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:56.498+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604813336:498796][1:0x7f7ffb631a80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 1 through 2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:56.889+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604813336:889036][1:0x7f7ffb631a80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 2 through 2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.525+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604813337:525554][1:0x7f7ffb631a80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Main recovery loop: starting at 1/25728 to 2/256"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.682+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604813337:682506][1:0x7f7ffb631a80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 1 through 2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.791+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604813337:791351][1:0x7f7ffb631a80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Recovering log 2 through 2"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.880+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604813337:880334][1:0x7f7ffb631a80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global recovery timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.880+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22430,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger message","attr":{"message":"[1604813337:880542][1:0x7f7ffb631a80], txn-recover: [WT_VERB_RECOVERY | WT_VERB_RECOVERY_PROGRESS] Set global oldest timestamp: (0, 0)"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.892+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":4795906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger opened","attr":{"durationMillis":3253}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.893+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"RECOVERY", "id":23987,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp","attr":{"recoveryTimestamp":{"$timestamp":{"t":0,"i":0}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.913+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":22262,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Timestamp monitor starting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.940+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20536,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Flow Control is enabled on this deployment"}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.950+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"FTDC",     "id":20625,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Initializing full-time diagnostic data capture","attr":{"dataDirectory":"/data/db/diagnostic.data"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.958+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.958+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23015,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Listening on","attr":{"address":"0.0.0.0"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2020-11-08T05:28:57.958+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23016,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Waiting for connections","attr":{"port":27017,"ssl":"off"}}
```

Comment: I noticed that the 2 pods are on different node. When I put them on same node, the mongo-express Pod will connect to the mongodb-service. I think it's probably CNI issue, but I don't have any idea for now.

Comment: Looks like you might have an issue with dns in your cluster. Can you check your coredns  pods if they are running fine? Can you provide their logs? Can you list your kube-system pods?

Comment: Thank you. It's the coredns pod issue. When I change the nameserver in my /etc/resolve.conf, all nodes in cluster are working! Really appreciate!!

Comment: Awesome! I`ll place small answer for better visibility.

Comment: Ok, no problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments those kind of problems usually indicates issues with coredns and dns resolution. Is it worth to mention that Kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/) goes thru couple of good dns troubleshooting steps:

- Check the local DNS configuration first

  ```
   kubectl exec -ti dnsutils -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
  ```
- Check if the DNS pod is running

  ```
   kubectl get pods --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
  ```
- Check for errors in the DNS pod

  ```
   kubectl logs --namespace=kube-system -l k8s-app=kube-dns
  ```
- Are DNS endpoints exposed?

  ```
   kubectl get endpoints kube-dns --namespace=kube-system
  ```

---

To summarize OP confirmed that the issue was related to coredns and changing the nameserver in  /etc/resolve.conf solved the issue.